# Find the field at a point perpendicular to a sheet of charge under the given constraints

Tags: electric-fields

Consider the following figure :
[image]

The square shaped (plane) sheet having uniform charge distribution and a side length of $d$ is placed in the $xy$ plane. A point $P$ is placed perpendicular to it and at a distance (perpendicular) of $\frac{d}{2}$ from its centre. Find the field at the point $P$.

One way of doing this is to use coulomb's law and integrate. But I have a doubt while using the Gauss Law. We can think of a cube and the position of this at the centre of the cube. Them using Gauss law, it's not hard to see why the field at $P$ would be $\frac{q}{6\epsilon_0}$.

1. But, how about not thinking that way and creating a cylindrical Gaussian surface from the centre of the sheet and doing? I can't do that.
2. Also, doing that way kind of seems that the perpendicular distance won't be of an issue? So, what if $P$ hadn't been perpendicular from the centre of the sheet and the distance hadn't been $\frac{d}{2}$ either? Would the field be same, still? (doesn't seem so, as the charges won't cancel out symmetrically)

Comment: '*Then using Gauss law, it's not hard to see why the field at P would be*  $\;\frac{Q}{6\epsilon_0}$ '. How did you prove that ??? I think I am missing something important here.  As $\;Q\;$  you mean of course the uniform surface charge density of the square that usually has as symbol  $\;\sigma\;$ and not the charge of the square.

Comment: @Frobenius I have edited it. Please check it once. Basically I was constructing a cube and placing the point charge at the centre of the cube. In this way, we can calculate the flux through $1$ face of the cube given that we know the flux through all six faces will be $\frac{q}{\epsilon_0}$, right?

Comment: Yes, but this answers  what is the electric flux through one of the six faces of a cube by an electric charge $\;q\;$ placed at the cube center and not to the totally different question of yours about what is the electric field $\;\mathbf{E}\;$ at the center of a cube produced by a face of the cube with uniform surface charge density $\;\sigma$. Is there a total confusion here and a misunderstanding of Gauss Law ???